# 3 phase heater to Single phase

Tags: electrical

I have this big immersion heater which my friend gave this to me. He said that this is originally design to be a 230V 9kW 3ph immersion heater (star).
I am planning to convert this to single phase.
Question is, how will the conversion affect the heating capacity of the heating element? Will it generate the same heat?

Comment: Depends. What voltage do you have access to? If 230 V phase to neutral then it's just a matter of joining all the three phases together.

Comment: hi Winny, thank you for your time. i can pay to install a 220-240V drawn from a 25 kVa transformer. will it be enough, if converted to 1ph, to acquire the same heating capacity as it can when it was on 3ph?

Comment: Yes. If the heater is made for 230 V phase-to-neutral three phase star connection and you supply it with 230 V with all three heater elements connected, you should be fine. You need 9 kVA to supply it.

Comment: @winny thank you very much

Comment: The three-phase water-heaters I know of have no return wire. They heat either with two elements (at low pressure, or by user selection) or with all three (full pressure). So this idea of you won't work. Check if that thing has a return wire at all.

Comment: @Janka, I assume it has a return wire, as Jef mentions it has a Star configuration. You are referring to a Delta configuration. But it is certainly good to check.

Comment: @Janka All the ~9 kW three phase heaters I’ve seen had return wire/star connection.

Comment: @Janka; This heater has 3 heating elements. previous wire config is a Wye connection. i previously connected all elements in parallel. but my circuit (with a 50A breaker) heated up. so i asked the local electricity providing company to quote me an upgrade so i can draw enough power from them, they said they can give me a connection directly from their mains with a 25 KVA transformer and duplex wires #2. no issue on the supply. only question was, if all connections was made correctly with a 220-240V source, will the heater be able to generate the same heat in single phase as it does in 3 phase?

Comment: @winny, thank you very much for giving some time to answer my questions. i appreciate it. i do wish i can return this favor in the future

Comment: Take EvertW's advice then.

Answer (score 1):

A long answer, as I get slightly worried when reading such questions. Messing with such powers in installations that are not designed for them can be a quick way to start a fire...

The simple answer is Yes, a 3ph heater at 230/380V will generate the same heat when powered with three 1ph 230V wires, as long as there is a return wire to connect the neutral wire to.

You could run it at 1/3 capacity by simply connecting 1 phase and the return. If you connect all three phases to a single phase, you would probably overload your wiring, as these are mostly rated at something like 3 to 4 kW. Please don't do that ;-)

When powering all three elements from a single phase, **you probably need to rewire the return circuit inside the heater**. At least check that it has heavy-gauge wire, at least 10mm<sup>2</sup>. In a proper 3p system, the return currents cancel each other out, but when using 1p they do not. Therefore the return circuit must be heavy enough to handle 50A from the point where the wires from the three heating elements come together. It may be that the heater was manufactured with a thick return circuit, but it may well be not. If the manufacturer counted on the returns cancelling out, the return wire may well be a flimsy after-thought that will burn through in 1p use.

To safely power the whole heater from a single phase, your electrical system would need to be capable of supplying something like 50 A. The cable running to the heater would need to be at least 2x10mm<sup>2</sup>, or 2x25mm<sup>2</sup> for longer distances. That is not cable you can pick up at the home depot... Alternatively, you could have separate cables for each phase. As most home-wiring is rated at 16-20A max, you would need to do that anyway. But then you need to make sure each wire is connected to a different fuse-group.

When using three separate cables, make sure they are the same length and type, to prevent a single return wire from being use more than the others.

But the limiting factor will probably be the rating of your electrical installation: at least where I come from (Netherlands), it is very expensive to be able to draw so much power single-phase. But in e.g. Germany and France, it is more common to have such power available.

Please note that installing such a system is not easy. Proper fuses need to be used that are able to interrupt the high short-circuit current, and the system needs to be grounded with another wire of at least 10mm<sup>2</sup>. If something goes wrong with the system and the wire touches the enclosure, the ground must be good enough to cause the circuit breaker to trip. If the system can not be grounded, there should be a differential circuit breaker capable of handling 50A.

Comment: thank you for answering my friend. i can ask some friends of mine to install a 25 kVa transformer and supply me proper wires for the sole purpose of running this heater. So you are saying that if i convert it to single phase, even if properly connected and with sufficient power supply, this will never heat the water as it does when it was on 3ph?

Comment: No, if you can safely transport sufficient current to the device, you could run it full-power. But what type of transformer are you talking about? A transformer, even though rated at 25KVA, can only supply as much power as it receives.

Comment: @EvertW: SE supports superscript, e.g., `<sup>2</sup>` and 
subscript `<sub>2</sub>` as well as HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&deg;`, `&mu;` and many others. They work in the posts but not in the comments. See also MathJAX which works in both.

Comment: @Transistor: I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: the power company said that they can assure i can draw a 90A max current from that 25 KVA transformer. and yes, here in my country, i will have to spend a lot of money to make this transformer installed. just for to confirm my friend, if i use he wire sizes you suggested, connected the 3 elements in parallel, provide a 50A 230V source then i can run this heater in same capacity as it has before conversion. did i got it right?

Comment: @Transistor: how come i cant read what you wrote? it appears on my screen as codes, no matter how many times i refresh the page.

Comment: There is one extra important point: the wiring of the return inside the heater. With a three-phase system, there is no return current as the currents cancel each other out. When powering with 1p, this is not the case, so the return should probably be re-wired with heavy-gauge wire, from the point where the three heater elements are joined together.

Comment: @EvertW, what wire gauge do you suggest then for the joint point of the returns

Comment: @JetBautista: 10mm^2 or more. I.e. a solid strip of copper at least 3x3 mm square, or round wire of 3.5mm diameter.

Comment: @Jet: I posted the codes as code (placing the code between backticks) so that Evert could read them. As explained, they work in the posts but not in the comments so I can't show them in operation in the comments. Read my original comment again.

Comment: @EvertW and Transistor, thank you very much for your time and suggestions. this has been of much help. thank you for not just answering my question, but also giving lots of technical and safety advises as well.